# Any way to make rack-livereload run faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rack-livereload on Windows using ruby_gntp. Currently it takes 5 seconds from I save a CSS file to I see the result in browser. 5-seconds is actually a longer time than it takes for manual refreshing the page.

Any way to make rack-livereload run faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning down the `:min_delay` and `:max_delay`. The default min time for livereload.js is 1000ms, and the browser slowly increases that check time up to the max (default 60000ms). See if this setting makes it any more responsive:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(
  ::Rack::Lock, ::Rack::LiveReload, :min_delay => 500, :max_delay => 3000
)
```